# Direct the output of the exec element in ant script to log file

Tags: bash, shell, ant

I am executing a shell script from an ant file. I want to capture the stdoutput of the shell script in the log file 'buillog-perform.txt'.
Below is my excerpt of the code. My full build is fine. But neither shell script is eecuted nor logs are captured in the buillog-perform.txt file.

Can someone help me with this? How can collect all the output and error if any of the shell script to this log file?

NOTE: I want to execute this target in parallel, hence using spawn attribute.

```
<target name="perform"
        description="This target for the perform.">     
    <exec dir="." executable="/bin/sh" spawn="true" output="buillog-perform.txt">
            <arg line="-c './abc.sh -c ${arg1}'" />
    </exec>
</target>
```

Comment: There is an "output" attribute on the ANT exec task: See: https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you one of the following solutions:

1) modify your code:

```
<arg line="-c './abc.sh -c ${arg1}' > stdout.txt 2> stderr.txt" />
```

2) add the following line at the beginning of your bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
exec &>> logfile.txt
…
```

Mind that `>>` is to append while `>` will just write. Also, you can use `> outANDerr.txt 2>&1` to have all the outputs in the same file.

For more info have a look here: http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/redirection